# Denoising segmentation map of image

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, rgb, mask

I have trained a face segmentation model on the CelebA-Mask-HQ dataset (https://github.com/switchablenorms/CelebAMask-HQ ) that is able to create a color segmentation mapping of an image with different colours for the background, eyes, face, hair, etc. The model produces a numpy array of shape (1024,1024,3). The outputted segmentation maps are a bit noisy, with some random pixels in the face labelled as eyes for example, or cloth labels popping up when it is actually background, please see the image below:

[image]

As you can see in the image, in the top left corner you see green pixels and in the face around the mustache you see green pixels (above the yellow upper lip map).

I would like to remove this 'noise' from the segmentation map, by changing these wrongly labeled small segments in the image, which are surrounded by larger correctly labeled areas, automatically to the most dominant color in that area (with adaptable window size). I could not find built-in opencv functionality for this. Do you know any efficient way to do this (I need to 'denoise' a large set of images, so ideally in a vectorized numpy-only way)?

It is very important that the image after denoising only contains the set of predefined label colors (19 different colors in total), so the noise needs to be recolored in an absolute manner without averaging (which would introduce new colors to the color palette of the image).

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I can point you away from openCV and towards scikit-image which I am more familiar with. I would tackle this using an approach borrowed from [this tutorial](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/segmentation/plot_label.html).

Specifically, I would do something like this:

```
label_image = label(image)

for region in regionprops(label_image):
    # only recolor areas that are under a certain threshold size
    if region.area <= 100:
        #get creative with which color to recolor with...
        minr, minc, maxr, maxc = region.bbox
        colors = np.bincount(label_image[minr : maxr, minc:maxc])
        max_color = -1
        for i in range(len(colors)):
            if (colors[i] > max_color) and (i != region.label):
                max_color = colors[i]
        crop_image = label_image[minr : maxr, minc:maxc]
        label_image[minr : maxr, minc:maxc][crop_image == region.label] = max_color
```

I haven't tried this code out...but I think something like this may work. Let me know if it is helpful or not.